# Adding div inside div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a header which contains a div .Inside the div i have placed a background image using CSS.Now inside this div i have put my logo div .Till now every thing is OK.Now i want to add a dropdownmenu 40px away from the logo but the problem is whatever i am trying to add is coming down to the header ..I am not able to trace out..

Here is my HTML..

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo"> <img src="image/logo.png" alt="logo"/>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is my CSS..

```
html, body {
color: #6F6F6F;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
font-size: 0.75em;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px !important; }

.img {
border: 0 none; }


.header-wrapper {
background: url("../image/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
float: left;
height: 77px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }

.header {
clear: both;
height: 77px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 20px;
width: 960px; }

.logo {
float: left;
height: 75px;
margin: 1px 49px 0 0;
width: 75px; }
```

and this is my dropdown code in HTML that i want to add ..

```
<div class='menu'>
<a class='hover-link'>Hover on Menu</a>
<div class='sub'>
<ul class='sub-options'>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and Here is my CSS..

```
<style type="text/css">

a{
text-decoration: none;
 }
.menu{
font-family: Arial;
color: #515151;
width: 200px;
position: relative;
height: 40px;
text-align:left;
width: 202px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu li a{
color: #515151;
display: block;
padding: 6px 15px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
}
.menu li a:hover{
background: #f44141;
color: #fff;
}
.sub{
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 200px;
padding: 40px 0 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #ddd;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
display: none;
}
a.hover-link{
width: 190px;
background: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
color: #515151;
position: absolute;
z-index: 110;
display: block;
padding: 10px 0 1px 10px;
height: 28px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.sub-options{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size: 11px;
 }
   </style>
```

Here is the Fiddle i which i want dropdown menu beside logo image instead it is coming down side..

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/T8snP/1/)

Please help me..

Comment: You've not shown any css code for your menu, have you tried `.menu {float;left;}`?

Comment: would be good to create a jsfiddle

Comment: @user3664608 make a fiddle it would help us find your bug

Comment: @Omega I have added the CSS for dropdown

Comment: @Vel I have updated post with fiddle..

Comment: @Vicky I have updated post with fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/T8snP/2/

You need to move your menu out of your logo div... HTML:

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="image/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div class='menu'>
<a class='hover-link'>Hover on Menu</a>

                <div class='sub'>
                    <ul class='sub-options'>
                        <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then float the menu div left with this CSS as suggested in the comment:

```
.menu {float: left;}
```

Comment: One clarification sir..Why is my logo image going down when i am adding margin: 10px auto; instead of margin: 0px auto;

Comment: @user3664608 sure, it's because you are adding 10px margin to the top and bottom of the element. The 10px applies to top and bottom, the auto applies to left and right. Good luck.

Comment: What to do if i want to placedown dropdown only and logo should be at original place

Comment: @user3664608 what are you applying `margin: 10px auto;` to? If you are applying it to the menu it shouldn't affect the logo.

Comment: But its affecting ...Logo also is going down

Answer (score 1):

You have to change as below
In html page

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="image/logo.png" alt="logo" /></div>
            <div class='menu'>
<a class='hover-link'>Hover on Menu</a>

                <div class='sub'>
                    <ul class='sub-options'>
                        <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add float in menu css as

```
float:left;
```

and set the margin in menu css as

```
margin: 0 auto 0 -40px;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo"> <img width="100%" height="100%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gtg9.jpg" alt="logo"/></div>
                  <div class='menu'>
<a class='hover-link'>Hover on Menu</a>
<div class='sub'>
<ul class='sub-options'>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>



            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS to be changed...

```
.menu{
font-family: Arial;
color: #515151;
width: 200px;
position: relative;
height: 40px;
text-align:left;
width: 202px;
margin-left:40px;
}
```

HERE is A [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u8BWq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-left:40px;

<div class="header-wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="image/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <div class='menu'>
           <a class='hover-link'>Hover on Menu</a>
            <div class='sub'>
                <ul class='sub-options'>
                    <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'>About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

your menu doesnt work? you have code for menu? check my code : http://fiddle.jshell.net/T8snP/5/

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
var curDd = $(".sub");
var dur = 350;
if(curDd.hasClass('shown')){
    curDd.fadeOut(dur/2);
    curDd.removeClass('shown');
} else {
    curDd.css({ opacity: 0.01, marginTop: 20 }).show().animate({ opacity: 1, marginTop: 0 }, { duration: 250, easing: "easeOutQuad" });
    curDd.addClass('shown');
}

return false;
});

$('body, html').click(function(){
    $('.shown').fadeOut(250).removeClass('shown');
});
```